# How to assign a list of numbers into letter grades

Tags: replacement

Here is my list:

```
collection = {76.6256, 51.9264, 50.238, 14.4203, 80.9205, 12.2036, 2.39568,
              38.2747, 12.4422, 29.9621}

collection /. {x_ /; x < 50 -> "F"}
```

and this gives me

> ```
> {76.6256, 51.9264, 50.238, "F", 80.9205, "F", "F", "F", "F", "F"}
> ```

as expected. But I want to add more rules with ranges like that. I'm not sure how to do this. I've tried:

```
collection /. {{x_ /; x < 50 -> "F"}, {x_ /; 50 <= x < 56 -> "D"},
               {x_ /; 56 <= x < 71 -> "C"}, {x_ /; 71 <= x < 85 -> "B"},
               {x_ /; 85 <= x <= 100 -> "A"}}
```

and that yields

> ```
> {{76.6256, 51.9264, 50.238, "F", 80.9205, "F", "F", "F", "F", "F"},
>    {76.6256, "D", "D", 14.4203, 80.9205, 12.2036, 2.39568, 38.2747, 12.4422, 29.9621},
>    {76.6256, 51.9264, 50.238, 14.4203, 80.9205, 12.2036, 2.39568, 38.2747,
>          12.4422, 29.9621},
>    {"B", 51.9264, 50.238, 14.4203, "B", 12.2036, 2.39568, 38.2747,
>          12.4422, 29.9621},
>    {76.6256, 51.9264, 50.238, 14.4203, 80.9205, 12.2036, 2.39568, 38.2747,
>          12.4422, 29.9621}}`
> ```

and I've tried a few others which don't even work at all. What is the simplest way of going about this? My real question is, how do I construct a list of rules where I can determine which range (0-50, 50-60, etc.) each number in the list is in?

Comment: Your replacement rules should be a list of rules, not a list of lists.  When it's a list `mylist` of lists, `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) returns a list of results, one for each list in `mylist`.  See @belisarius's answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just put all your rules in a list. You don't need the lower bounds. The first matching rule in the list is applied:

```
s = {x_ /; x < 50 -> "F", x_ /; x < 56 -> "D", x_ /; x < 71 -> "C", 
     x_ /; x < 85 -> "B", x_ /; x <= 100 -> "A"};

collection /. s

(* {"B", "D", "D", "F", "B", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F"}*)
```

Comment: Crap! I swear I tried this exact same thing and it didn't work for me! But perhaps I forgot a bracket or something. This is definitely the simplest and was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much and thanks to everyone who contributed. Your help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 17):

```
Clear[grade]

grade[x_?NumericQ] = Piecewise[{
    {"F", x < 50}, {"D", x < 56},
    {"C", x < 71}, {"B", x < 85}},
   "A"];

collection = {76.6256, 51.9264, 50.238,
   14.4203, 80.9205, 12.2036, 2.39568,
   38.2747, 12.4422, 29.9621};

grade /@ collection
```

> {"B", "D", "D", "F", "B", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F"}

Answer (score 10):

For a large number of values a better method is to use [`Interpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interpolation.html) with an order of zero.

First build the [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html):

```
points = {{50, "F"}, {56, "D"}, {71, "C"}, {85, "B"}, {100, "A"}};

fn = Interpolation[points, InterpolationOrder -> 0];
```

Then:

```
fn[collection] // Quiet
```

> ```
> {"B", "D", "D", "F", "B", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F"}
> ```

---

### Performance

I claimed that for "a large number of values" the method above is superior to replacement rules.  Here is a BenchmarkPlot  to support that assertion:

```
letters = StringJoin /@ Tuples[CharacterRange["A", "Z"], 3];
numbers = Sort @ RandomSample[Range[100000], 26^3];
points = {numbers, letters}\[Transpose];
rand = RandomReal[100000, 50000];
f1 = ReplaceAll[rand, (x_ /; x < # -> #2) & @@@ #] &;
f2 = Interpolation[#, InterpolationOrder -> 0][rand] &;
Off[InterpolatingFunction::dmval]

Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

BenchmarkPlot[{f1, f2}, Sort@RandomSample[points, #] &, 2^Range[14], 
 "IncludeFits" -> True, TimeConstraint -> 30]
```

[image]

- Note the logarithmic scale.
- The *x* axis is the number of levels (letters) in the assignment.
- Time to construct each `InterpolatingFunction` is *included*; reuse would be faster.

`ReplaceAll` is faster with only a few levels, but from eight and up `InterpolatingFunction` is faster, and with many levels orders of magnitude faster.

Answer (score 9):

More handy in case of more notes (?).

```
notes = {"F", "D", "C", "B", "A"};
bl = BinLists[collection, {{0, 50, 56, 71, 85, 100}}];

collection /. Flatten@MapThread[Thread[# -> #2] &, {bl, notes}]
```

> ```
> {"B", "D", "D", "F", "B", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F"}
> ```

---

or

```
notes = {"F", "D", "C", "B", "A"}
levels = {50, 56, 71, 85, 100}
Block[{x},
 Function[note[x_] := Which[##]] @@ Flatten[MapThread[{x <= #, #2} &, 
                                                      {levels, notes}]]

     ]

note /@ collection
```

Comment: +1 I've seen cases where 26 letters aren't enough

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Fold` to successively apply a list of rules.

```
Fold[#1 /. #2 &, collection, {{x_ /; x < 50 -> "F"},
    {x_ /; 50 <= x < 56 -> "D"}, {x_ /; 56 <= x < 71 -> "C"},
    {x_ /; 71 <= x < 85 -> "B"}, {x_ /; 85 <= x <= 100 -> "A"}}]
```

> ```
> {"B", "D", "D", "F", "B", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F"}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

```
collection /. 
 x_?NumberQ :> Which[x < 50, "F", x < 56, "D", x < 71, "C", x < 85, "B", x <= 100, "A"]
```

> {"B", "D", "D", "F", "B", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F"}

Timing comparison for 1000 random reals repeated 1000 times

[image]

Comment: (+1) `timings={2.53, 2.71, 3.01, 3.42, 4.68, 5.09, 13.59}; gradesF[{10, Infinity}, Reverse@{"ok", "Ouch"}][timings]`:)

Comment: @kguler your solution has merits (flexibility) which - in many cases - should be more important than seconds :)

Comment: Please see the timing plot in my answer.  It doesn't invalidate your timings but it clarifies and supports what I meant about the performance of `Interpolation`.

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[gradesF];
gradesF[x_: {49, 59, 79, 89, 100}, y_: {"A", "B", "C", "D", "F"}] := 
  Function[{z}, Piecewise[{#, z < #2} & @@@ (Flatten /@ Thread[{Reverse@y, x}])], Listable];

gradesF[][collection]
(* {"C","D","D","F","B","F","F","F","F","F"} *)

gradesF[{50, 56, 71, 85, 100}][collection]
(* {"B","D","D","F","B","F","F","F","F","F"} *)

gradesF[{69, 100}, {"Pass", "Fail"}][collection]
(* {"Pass","Fail","Fail","Fail","Pass","Fail","Fail","Fail","Fail",\
"Fail"} *)
```