# Map and Module to convert numerical value to grade

Tags: functions, homework

I have an assignment due next week, I've answered all other questions except for this one.

I am required to use `Module` and `Map` functions to convert a score to a grade system. For example, if the score is 81, then the grade would be 'A'. I am not quite sure on how to even start this.

Comment: see the examples in [Piecewise](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) in the docs.

Comment: [Related, if not a dupe.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60497)